# match the first two bits (only) in a digital stream line (byte) using grep

Tags: regex, grep

How should I match the first two bits (first occurrence only) in a digital stream line (1 byte line) using grep, in one direction only, i.e.  (`01` but not `10` in `01051015`); 
I've been tested:

```
grep -E '^[0-9]\{2\}$' | grep -Po --color '01' <<< 01051015
> 010-10-- (current output)

$cat -n test.txt
1 0001021113
2 0202031011
3 0103031113
4 .......... 
$ grep -oE '^[0-1][0-9]\{2,2\}' | grep -E '(10)' ./test.txt > matchedList.txt
$ cat -n matchedList.txt 
1 0001021113 
2 0202031011 
3 0103031113
```

But I need to parse and math the first "par occurrence", (in this case '10') ... in that specific order and one direction (like in line 2); so the correct utput should be: `2 0202031011`

Tkx in advance
L.

Comment: try to add some sample of input and expected output (representative case) when possible

Comment: $ cat -n test.txt
     1  0001021113
     2  0202031011
     3  0103031113
     4  ..........
$ grep -oE '^[0-1][0-9]\{2,2\}' | grep  -E '(10)' ./test.txt > matchedList.txt

$ cat -n matchedList.txt
     1  0001021113
     2  0202031011
     3  0103031113

But I need to parse and math the first "par occurrence", (in this case  '10') 
...in that specific order and one direction (like in line 2); 
so the correct utput should be: 
2  0202031011 
         --

Please advise ?!

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -m 1 -e '^01' YourFile
```

where:

- `01` is your *first 2 bit* to find
- `-m 1` limit to 1st occurence

Comment: it does work for only one stream line, but not for each line of the parsed file.
What about the second part of the requirement, meaning output the matched stream line to a new file.
I still using 
$$ grep -oE '^[0-1][0-9]\{2,2\}' | egrep -e '(10)' ./test.txt > matchedList.txt
but it doesn't work very well, so I have to manually rework a lot. 
Pls advise;
L.

Comment: a stream is 1 line for you ? this grep stop after 1 line where the pattern match. maybe a better sample of expected output (based on your test.txt file from post)  will help for my understanding

Comment: A string is one line only (0101101221), that includes ten bits ( or 5 pairs of bits: 01 01 10 12 21).
I need a "grep" that parses every string line in (5 pairs: 01 01 10 12 21) 
further search for the piped second "grep": (... | grep -E '12'), 
and output/file the strings line that match the selected pair ('12').
The other problem is that my "grep" also match not only the correct pair ('12')  but he invalid pairs (1 21) as well.

Comment: Example:
1 0001121113 
2 0212031011 
3 0103031121 
4 0001021113 
5 0202031021 
6 0103031113 
So, for the following: $$ grep -oE '^[0-1][0-9]\{2,2\}' | grep -E '(12)' ./test.txt > matchedList.txt

Comment: the corresponding output in (matchedList.txt) will be lines:
1 00 01 12 11 13 
3 01 03 03 11 21
4 00 01 02 11 23 
5 02 02 03 12 21 
The output I need should be (string line "1 00 01 12 11 13" that match the correct parsed pair '12'.